Exchange form of multidimension array natively in PHP
Just out of curiousity..
is it possible to change the form of a multidimension array
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_user] => 79
            [nama] => Sasha
            [id_app] => 908989898
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_user] => 91
            [nama] => Edward
            [id_app] => 23232323
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id_user] => 50
            [nama] => Jhon
            [id_app] => 1212121212
        )
)

into
Array
(
    [id_user] => Array
        (
            [0] => 79
            [1] => 91
            [2] => 50
        )

    [nama] => Array
        (
            [0] => Sasha
            [1] => Edward
            [2] => Jhon
        )

    [id_app] => Array
        (
            [0] => 908989898
            [1] => 23232323
            [2] => 1212121212
        )
)

All the array is actually pulled from a database table so the structure will always consistent.. so taking this into account...
using native function and not by looping it manually?
For now, I am using PHP and manually loop it, but if in any other language it is possible please inform me.

@mickmackusa can you please indicate which answer in the claimed dupe which answers this question?

Equally unreliable as Nigel's answer (when dealing with a 2d array containing only 1 row): var_export(array_merge_recursive(...$array));

I've posted an answer on the canonical that accommodates your styling constraints and exposes potential data structure caveats which will corrupt the result.  I've also included stable functional-style techniques which are more convoluted than classic language construct iteration (but just as stable).  I've seen array_reduce() choke on very high volumes of array data (while other array functions didn't have trouble).  My advice is that if you prefer to have a clean function for transposition, write a helper function in your application that uses 2 foreach loops and call that.

Thanks for all the comment, and the dupe question is actually kind of similar but also kind of different.. I want to know if there is a native function for this.. as i am already currently loop it trough..
and the answer from @mickmackusa is actually working considering my array is from a database table... so the function is
array_merge_recursive($array);

You can do it in a few stages.
First extract the values (from Transposing multidimensional arrays in PHP).
You also need the key names, so assuming they are all present in the first array using array_keys().
Then put them together using array_combine()...
$values = array_map(null, ...$a);
$keys = array_keys($a[0]);
$newArray = array_combine($keys, $values);
print_r($newArray);


This answer, while it works on the provided sample input, is not stable/reliable when the input may be an empty array or may contain only 1 row of data or the rows' associative elements may have differing orders or columns not in the first row may exist in subsequent rows.
